# why are there dll files copied to my project's Bin/Debug folder upon compilation despite not referencing any of those libraries?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2012

I am confused why Visual Studio creates/copies tons of library dlls into my project's bin/Debug folders although I have not referenced any of those libraries? The dlls represent libraries used in other projects of the same solution that above mentioned project is under but I do not get why unreferenced libraries in one given project are still copies into the bin/... folders. I use NuGet but I made sure that the solution wide NuGet manager only includes specific projects that are supplied with chosen libraries.

Comment: if project A references project B and project B references dll C then project A most likely won't function without dll C (if any functionality from this dll is indirectly used). That's why dll C is copied to bin of project A

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If project A references project B and project B references dll C then project A most likely won't function without dll C (if any functionality from this dll is indirectly used). That's why dll C is copied to the "bin" folder of project A.

Comment: @zespri, one question though: You say "if any functionality from this dll is indirectly used". I guess this statement is irrelevant because even if I just reference B in A and not call code that requires referenced C in B I still end up with all the libraries that B itself references.

Comment: Thats essentially the problem I am facing. I built a shared library that iself references other external third-party libraries. But each time I link to my built library no matter whether I use or not use any of the library content, my project immediately blows up to 100mb because of all the copied dlls.

Comment: @Freddy .net is indeed loads dlls only when they are somehow actually used. So it IS possible that dll is referenced, but if you delete it it does not affect the application. It is most likely to occur if you are using some library for a single function, when the library require a dependency and the function in question does not. There is not much you can do here. You can either use a different (leaner) library, or use static analysis tool to confirm what's used and what's not and finally if you are 100% sure that some referenced library is not used you may include a build step to delete it.

Comment: How does one find out which of the directly referenced dll's is referencign the extra dlls? I am browsing through a solution in ILSpy and I cannot find tese extra dlls anywhere even at deeper levels of dll dependencies.

Comment: @pingo - not enough information. what "these extra dlls" are you talking about? Note that comments to this answer probably is not the best place to discuss this. If you can ask it as an on-topic question  on this site, you better do that. If you can't then you better ask this question elsewhere.

Comment: @zaspri - sorry, I was not clear enough, with "these extra dlls" I meant all projects/dlls that are indirectly referenced. In your example that would be C.dll and whatever else B and C reference. I already found a solution via Mono.Cecil and made this https://github.com/pingec/ILDependencyGraph

Answer (score 0):

If you're using NuGet, are you installing the packages to every project, or selecting only the ones that use it?  I'm not clear if you mean that by 'but I made sure that the solution wide NuGet manager only includes specific projects that are supplied with chosen libraries.'

Comment: I install them only to selected projects, excluding the project in question